# How to turn on emulator screen?

Tags: android, android-emulator

In Android Studio 3.0 emulators save their state after close. So, if I turn off a power (in emulator), it will turn off a screen. I can't turn it on anymore.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This issue can be solved by starting emulator with cold boot. As @CoolMind said Tools > AVD Manager, in actions tab push down arrow and select cold boot now.

Answer (score 8):

I am using IntelliJ IDEA, but basically it is the same with Android Studio. Firstly, open `Tools > Android > AVD Manager`, in the `Actions` column, click the arrow button then choose:

1. **Cold Boot Now**

Try a cold boot first.

2. **Wipe Data**

In case cold boot cannot solve the problem or it occurs again when you start the emulator next time, you should wipe data.

Comment: I agree with you. Will add plus to you.

Answer (score 4):

In **Android Studio 4.0 for Mac**:

- <kbd>Tools</kbd> >
- <kbd>AVD Manager</kbd> >
- [Edit your current device] >
- <kbd>Show Advanced Settings</kbd> >
- <kbd>Emulated Performance</kbd> >
- <kbd>Boot Option</kbd>: <kbd>Cold Boot</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

A rude way to refresh an emulator is Tools > Android > AVD Manager, then find your emulator and at right side click gray arrow, then select "Wipe Data".

Answer (score 0):

Selecting Cold Boot the emulater starts as from a power-up, it solves will your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).